# Data not displaying on load time in angular

Tags: angular

In my project i am trying to display the users data in UI. But i am getting issues to display data

**Here my users.json data**

```
{
  "success": true,
  "summary": {
    "total_registrations": 100,
    "verified": 30,
    "pending_verifications": 20,
    "profile_complete": 20,
    "profile_pending": 10,
    "mw_verified": 10,
    "mw_pending": 10
  },
  "data": [{
      "user_id": 1,
      "user_first_name": "Peter",
      "user_last_name": "Parker",
      "user_age": "25",
      "user_gender": "M",
      "user_city": "Nasik",
      "user_religion": "Hindu",
      "user_caste": "Hindu",
      "user_profession": "Self Employed",
      "mw_notes": "mw_notes",
      "user_package": "PLT",
      "user_profiles_allocated": "0",
      "mw_representative": "",
      "user_photo": "male.jpg"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 2,

      "user_first_name": "Peter",
      "user_last_name": "Parker",
      "user_age": "25",
      "user_gender": "M",
      "user_city": "Nasik",
      "user_religion": "Hindu",
      "user_caste": "Hindu",
      "user_profession": "Self Employed",
      "mw_notes": "mw_notes",
      "user_package": "PLT",
      "user_profiles_allocated": "0",
      "mw_representative": "",
      "user_photo": "male.jpg"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 3,
      "user_first_name": "Peter",
      "user_last_name": "Parker",
      "user_age": "25",
      "user_gender": "M",
      "user_city": "Nasik",
      "user_religion": "Hindu",
      "user_caste": "Hindu",
      "user_profession": "Self Employed",
      "mw_notes": "mw_notes",
      "user_package": "PLT",
      "user_profiles_allocated": "0",
      "mw_representative": "",
      "user_photo": "male.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

**service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getAllUsers(){
    return this.http.get<any>('assets/users.json')
  }
}
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Table } from 'primeng/table';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('dt') table: Table;

  allUsers:any = [];

  summary: any = {};
  
  constructor(private _userSerivce: UserService) { }
  
  ngOnInit():void {

   this._userSerivce.getAllUsers().subscribe(
      result => {
        this.summary = result.summary;
        this.allUsers = result.data;
        console.log(result.summary);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let user of allUsers">
        <td>{{user.user_id}}</td>
        <td>{{user.user_first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.user_gender}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    Total Registration : {{summary.total_registrations}}
  </div>
</div>
```

when i am running this project on browser all data are successfully displayed in the console but it's not display in UI window but if i click anywhere in window then data display successfully.. i don't know what's happening there

**Here my routing module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
       component: DashboardComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'subscription-packages',
        component: SubscriptionPackagesComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'coupon',
        component: CouponCodeComponent
      },
      {
        path:'user-details',
        component: UserDetailsComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: 'errors/404',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class PagesRoutingModule {}
```

other component's are working properly only dashboard component are run like this.

Comment: Try add *ngIf to your table, *ngIf="allUsers && allUsers.length"

Comment: I's not working   @Mateusz Ścigała

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a problem of `ChangeDetection`.

Try to use the `markForCheck` from `ChangeDetectorRef`([more here](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef))

```js
import { Table } from 'primeng/table';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('dt') table: Table;

  allUsers:any = [];

  summary: any = {};
  
  constructor(
    private _userSerivce: UserService,
    private _detector: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) { }
  
  ngOnInit():void {

   this._userSerivce.getAllUsers().subscribe(
      result => {
        this.summary = result.summary;
        this.allUsers = result.data;
        console.log(result.summary);
        this._detector.markForCheck()
      }
    )
  }
}
```